# User Permission - Display edit in view (express, handlebars)

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, handlebars.js

At the moment I have user profiles that are rendered using Handlbars as such:

```
exports.profile = function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({username: req.params.username}).exec(function(err, user){
    res.render('profile/view', {
      user: req.user,
      name: user.name,
      username: user.username
    });
  });
};
```

On the rendered template at `profile/view` I would like to display an edit button **if** the user can edit the profile being viewed.

```
<a href="/edit/usernamehere">Edit your profile here</a>
```

Additional information:

- Every user us currently authenticated with passport-local strategy
- Currently have some basic middleware on the route

**Middleware**

```
app.get('/:username', isAuth, user.profile);

  function isAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }
    req.flash('alert', 'First you need to log in');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
```

I've looked into middleware for express such as [connect-roles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-roles) and I don't think its what I need?

What I'm thinking is that I should pass a boolean within the local variables of the `res.render()` method which then allow me to use handlebars to display the button or not.

```
{{#if profileOwner }}<a href="#">...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by hydrating your template model with a `profileOwner` privilege as you suggested. Suppose you wanted to only allow users to edit their own profiles. Using `connect-roles` you could set up a rule like this:

```
user.use('profile owner', function (req, action) {
    return req.isAuthenticated() &&
        req.user.username === req.params.username;
})
```

And your route logic could then be:

```
exports.profile = function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({username: req.params.username}).exec(function(err, user){
    res.render('profile/view', {
      user: req.user,
      name: user.name,
      username: user.username,
      profileOwner: req.user.is('profile owner')
    });
  });
};
```

Then your mustache "if" syntax would look like this:

```
{{#profileOwner}}<a href="#">Tada</a>{{/profileOwner}}
```

The negative case can be handled like so if you wish:

```
{{^profileOwner}}You are not a profile owner!{{/profileOwner}}
```

Comment: Where would I go about adding functionality to test a profileOwner?

Comment: Oh. I tuned in to the templating aspect of your question but I guess its more about how to do user authorization in node? Can you tell us more about how you've set this up? Are you using passport for example?

Comment: Updated my answer incorporate more authz details. There are many ways to structure authz rules, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it might be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I think is creating an helper that check if userCan for you. Here the helper:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifUserCan', function(action, options) {
    var actions = action.split(/\s*,\s*/);

    for (var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
        if (this.userCan(actions[i])) {
            return options.fn(this);
        }
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

You can use it as follow:

```html
{{#ifUserCan 'show all store categories'}}
    <li><a href="/categories">{{__ 'Show categories'}}</a></li>
{{/ifUserCan}}
```